# ListView and ArrayAdapter<String>

Tags: android, arrays

Is there anything bad with this code?

The thing is that the "test" is not displayed in `ListView`.

Java:

```
private ListView namesListView;
private ArrayList<String> names;
private ArrayAdapter<String> namesAA;
...
namesListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.clear();
names.add(0, "test");
namesAA = new ArrayAdapter<String> ( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names );
namesListView.setAdapter(namesAA);
...
```

XML:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Comment: The java code is inside the `onCreate` method?

Comment: Is this an activity or a listactivity?

Comment: no need to clear names array list here bcs you are already assigning it and after clearing,and is this code in onCreate method?

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried this?

```
namesAA = new ArrayAdapter<String> ( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, names );
```

By the way, why are you specifying the place of the item? You are clearing the arraylist so adding `names.add("test");` is better, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I pick up is that `layout_height` is set to `wrap_content` which will not allocate more height than it absolutely needs. This is sort of paradoxal for a scrolling view, because there's really no physical limit to how small it could be.

I'm guessing that's where your problem is.

Comment: Hi,

I tried to change it to "fill_parent" it has not effect.

STeN

Comment: If the arraylist has at least one element, than specifying the layout_height property as wrap_content is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ListActivity or ListFragment you'll need to change your Listview's name to: android:id="@+id/android:list"

edit: wow, just realized this question is three years old

Comment: nice observation 3 year old didn't noticed

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in the ListView