# Android ArrayAdapter<String> Error

Tags: android, eclipse, string, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I need to create a spinner from a string. Until now I use an ArrayAdapter, but it's not working. This is my code

```
ArrayList<String> aus=new ArrayList<String>();
            if(results.length!=0){
                for(int i=0;i<results.length;i++)
                    aus.add(results[i].get_nome());
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, aus);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                locale.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
```

locale is a Spinner type
results it's a my class and get_nome return a string
I have this error:    "The costructor of ArrayAdapter(new Handler(){},int, ArrayList is undefined"

Comment: result is int or string?

Comment: aus.add(results[i].get_nome());
what is get_nome ? i think this is mistake and thats why not fill data into arraylist

Comment: String results[];
      results[0] = "asd";
        ArrayList<String> aus=new ArrayList<String>();
        if(results.length!=0){
            for(int i=0;i<results.length;i++)
                aus.add(results[i]);

Comment: results is't a personal class and get_nome() retrurns a string

Comment: make aus.add(results[i]); and try

Comment: does't work because results is a array of object(type Locale)

Comment: yes but the error is in "ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, aus);"

Comment: try ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157157/listview-and-arrayadapterstring

Comment: nothing i the error is in the costructor of arrayadapter<String>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're creating the adapter in an inner class.. You should do

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivityClass.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, aus);
```